# MNLogit fit and summary displays all nan

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, statsmodels

I am new to ML world.
Trying to do Logistic regression from Stats model. However, when I execute I get current Function Value as `nan`
I tried checking if dataframe is finite as I saw it might be cause. But that turns out to be ok.
Referred the below link, but did not work in my case.

update : Still did not figure it out

Referred Links :

1. [MNLogit in statsmodel returning nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507396/mnlogit-in-statsmodel-returning-nan)
2. [numpy: Invalid value encountered in true_divide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842884/numpy-invalid-value-encountered-in-true-divide)

Please can someone help me on this ?

[![Finite Values result][1]][1]

[![Error with current function value as nan][2]][2]
[![All Nans in summary][3]][3]

Comment: do you have large x values? overflow in `exp` often occurs during optimization when some x values are large, try rescaling.

Comment: Thanks this was the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your problem and the solution identified in referred link#1. {FYI it gives the same error as shown in your screen capture.}
It seems like you need to identify a different solving method.
In your code you can try to do the following to have the same solution as link#1.

```
result=logit_model.fit(method='bfgs')
```

I'm sorry if you already tried this. Unfortunately, I cannot test it without the dataset, let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the response, The original issue was large values which needs rescaling